# How to send wp_mail with attachment (file-path in variable)

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to send an email with attachment using wordpress' wp_mail function.

With this function it works fine to send emails but the attachment isn't there when i check my email.

```
function dd_send_email(){

    $dd_path = $_POST['upload_image'];
    // echo $dd_path;

    $email_sent = false;

    // get email template data
    $email_template_object = dd_get_current_options();


    // if email template data was found
    if ( !empty( $email_template_object ) ):

        // setup wp_mail headers
        $wp_mail_headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        $mail_attachment = $dd_path; 

        // use up_mail to send email
        $email_sent = wp_mail( array( 'example@mail.no') , $email_template_object['dd_emne_forhaandsbestilling'], $email_template_object['dd_email_text_forhaandsbestilling'], $wp_mail_headers, $mail_attachment );

    endif;

    return $email_sent;

}
```

The variable `$dd_path` (something like: http://localhost/norskeanalyser/wp-content/uploads/Testanalyse-2.pdf) contains the path of the file which i do upload from the media uploader in another function.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found the answer by myself. Because wp_mail needs the file path like this  /uploads/2016/03/example.jpg we have to convert our url to a path like this.

I did achive this by doing the following and thought i can share it with you:

```
    // change url to path   
    $dd_url = $_POST['upload_image'];
    $dd_path = parse_url($dd_url);

    // cut the path to right directory
    $array = explode("/norskeanalyser/wp-content", $dd_path['path']);
    unset($array[0]);
    $text = implode("/", $array);
```

and then i did save the `$text` into `$mail_attachment` and called it in wp_mail like above.